# Adjusting for a mediator to capture cross sectional relationship

Tags: multivariate-analysis, causality

We are fitting a linear model using cross-sectional data to inspect the relationship between some exposure and an outcome (disease status, measured continuously). Duration of disease was also captured in these data, and individuals with a positive diagnosis have undergone a relationship with their care provider to help manage their disease status. Presumably there were several individuals whom we didn't capture because they had a short duration of disease, a poor relationship with their care provider, and died before they were eligible to be included in this study.

My question is the following:

Suppose we only observe $[t, X_{i,t}, Y_{i, t}]$. $i$ is the subject level, and $t$ is the time, say years since diagnosis of disease. X is the exposure, Y is the disease status both evaluated cross sectionally with $t$ varying randomly between subjects from 0 to 20.

If we believe the following linear model $$E[Y_{i,t}|X_{i,t}, Y_{i, t-1}] = \alpha + \beta X_{i,t} + \gamma Y_{i, t-1}$$, then how might additional adjustment for $t$ reduce the bias of $\tilde{\beta}$ in the biased model: $$E[Y_{i,t}|X_{i,t} = \tilde{\alpha} + \tilde{\beta} X_{i,t}$$?